# XPath "following siblings before"

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to select elements (a) with XPath 1.0 (or possibly could be with Regex) that are following siblings of particular element (b) but only preceed another b element.

```
<img><b>First</b><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/first-href">First Href</a> - 19:30<br>
<img><b>Second</b><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/second-href">Second Href</a> - 19:30<br>
<img>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/third-href">Third Href</a> - 19:30<br>
```

I tried to make the sample as close to real world as possible. So in this scenario when I'm at element

```
<b>First</b>
```

I need to select

```
<a href="/first-href">First Href</a>
```

and when I'm at

```
<b>Second</b>
```

I need to select

```
<a href="/second-href">Second Href</a> 
<a href="/third-href">Third Href</a>
```

Any idea how to achieve that? Thank you!

Comment: Can we assume the xml is well formed, that is the `br` elements are actually `<br />` ?  Also that the `img` elements have content and end with `/>`?  It really would help if "real world" included well formed XML if not XPath is not an option.

Comment: Being real world example, of course it is not well formed. I wish it was :( However, I'm using Html Agility Pack (.NET) to process the markup and it tolerates ill-formed documents, if that's any help.

Comment: There is no reason to assume that "real world" implies mal-formed xml.  There are plenty of examples of html delivered as well formed xml.  Of course had you mentioned agility in the question it would have made the scenario clearer.  Added appropriate tag.

Comment: Interested in a single XPath expression solution? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamically create this XPath:

```
following-sibling::a[preceding-sibling::b[1][.='xxxx']]
```

where 'xxxx' is the replaced with the text of the current `<b>`.

This is assuming that all the elements actually *are* siblings. If they are not, you can try to work with the `preceding` and `following` axes, or you write a more specific XPath that better resembles document structure.

In XSLT you could also use:

```
following-sibling::a[
  generate-id(preceding-sibling::b[1]) = generate-id(current())
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is **a solution which is just a single XPath expression**.

Using **the Kaysian formula for intersection** of two nodesets `$ns1` and `$ns2`:

```
  $ns1[count(. | $ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

We simply substitute `$ns1` with the nodeset of `<a>` siblings that follow the current `<b>` node, and we substitute `$ns2` with the nodeset of `<a>` siblings that precede the next `<b>` node.

**Here is a complete transformation that uses this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/b"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b">
    At: <xsl:value-of select="."/>

    <xsl:variable name="vNextB" select="following-sibling::b[1]"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vA-sAfterCurrentB" select="following-sibling::a"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vA-sBeforeNextB" select=
    "$vNextB/preceding-sibling::a
    |
     $vA-sAfterCurrentB[not($vNextB)]
    "/>

    <xsl:copy-of select=
     "$vA-sAfterCurrentB
              [count(.| $vA-sBeforeNextB)
              =
               count($vA-sBeforeNextB)
               ]
    "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
    <img/>
    <b>First</b>
    <br />&#xA0;&#xA0;
    <img/>&#xA0;&#xA0;
    <a href="/first-href">First Href</a> - 19:30
    <br />
    <img/>
    <b>Second</b>
    <br />
    <img/>&#xA0;&#xA0;
    <a href="/second-href">Second Href</a> - 19:30
    <br />
    <img/>&#xA0;
    <a href="/third-href">Third Href</a> - 19:30
    <br />
</t>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

```
   At: First <a href="/first-href">First Href</a>
    At: Second <a href="/second-href">Second Href</a>
<a href="/third-href">Third Href</a>
```